# How do I insert a lot of entities in a Play! Job?

Tags: java, jpa, transactions, batch-file, playframework

In my application I have to simulate various situations for analysis. Thus insert a (very) large amount of lines into a database. (We're talking about a very large amount of data...several billion)

### Model

```
@Entity
public class Case extends Model {

    public String url;
}
```

### Job

```
public class Simulator extends Job {

    public void doJob() {

         for (int i = 0; i !=) {

             // Somestuff

             new Case(someString).save();
         }
    }
}
```

After half an hour, ***there is still nothing in the database***. But debug traces show Play inserts some stuff. I suspect it is some kind of cache.

I've tried about everything :

```
Model.em().flush();
```

Changes nothing.

```
Model.em().getTransaction().commit();
```

throws *TransactionRequiredException occured : no transaction is in progress*

```
Model.em().setFlushMode(FlushModeType.COMMIT);
Model.em().setFlushMode(FlushModeType.AUTO);
```

Changes nothing.

I've also tried **@NoTransaction** annotations everywhere :

- Class & functions in Controller
- Class Case
- Overriding save method in Model
- Class & functions of my Job

Getting quite desperate. Every kind of advice is welcome.

EDIT : After a little research, the first row appears in database. The associated ID is about 550.000. That means about half a million rows are somewhere in between my application and database.

Comment: What exception does commit() throw?

Comment: TransactionRequiredException occured : no transaction is in progress.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
em.getTransaction().begin();
em.persist(model);
em.getTransaction().commit();
```

You can't commit a transaction before you begin it.

Comment: That is indeed a solution. Brutal but working. Added a manual cache of a few thousand inserts. But that is not telling me why my database still is empty.

Comment: Hmmm what kind of data base are you using?  Better yet, can you post the database connection url you are using.

Comment: I'm using a Mysql connection (for dev, Postgresql in production) and the default jdbc configuration of Play. I've also tried with fs and mem, same behaviour.

Comment: For the moment, the best solution found. And since I'm running out of time to playh around, I'll stick with that... for the moment.

Comment: This worked for me. Though instead of using @NoTransaction (which I couldn't get to work), I simply did an initial em.getTransaction().commit(); at the very beginning of my method. When batching commits into group of 1000 records, it runs at least an order of magnitude faster!

Answer (score 0):

as per [documentation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.1/jobs), the job should have its own transaction enabled as Play request do, so that's not the issue. Try doing this:

```
for (int i = 0; i !=) {

  // Somestuff

  Case tmp = new Case(someString);
  tmp = JPA.em().merge(tmp);
  tmp.save();
}
```

The idea is that you add the newly created object to the EntityManager explicitly before saving, making sure the object is part of the "dirty objects" that will be persisted.

Comment: I just gave it a try. Changes nothing. The objects aren't peristed either. Or should I say, do not appear in the database.

Comment: @zenklys completely odd, I know I use objects in jobs and they are modified/stored transactionally... oh well, at least it seems you found a fix :)

Answer (score -1):

You need to instruct Play! when it should run your job by annotating your class with one of these annotations @OnApplicationStart, @Every or @On.

Please check Play! documentation on [jobs](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.0/jobs)

Comment: Triggering the job is not the problem, it is working well. It's the insertion in the database itself that causes the problem.